# Issue related to vertical line in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have Crystal Report in VS 2008. The report has group header section above the detail section and group like display in image below:

[image]

I have drawn vertical image in detail section but it displays like in following Image:

[image]

I also tried to scratched vertical line below the detail section but it in output line goes out of the box  like in following Image

[image]

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS2008 open this report. Select the line and go to **Properties Window**. There you can reduce the value of **Bottom**. So your line height will be reduced. Reduce the value of Bottom until the vertical line fits the horizontal line.

Hope this helps you, Leave comments if any !

Answer (score 1):

in the report designer you should zoom the `Section3, Details` and resize the vertical line to end exactly when it reaches the horizontal line. I know it's a pain and in Crystal is not as friendly as it is in other reports designers (like in my favourite one DevExpress XtraReports) but still you can do it if you zoom and carefully handle the size of the line object.