# How to resize the line objects in Crystal Reports

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, resize

I am using VS 2008 and I have made a report using crystal reports that comes with VS 2008.

I am using a box object in my report and then I am using line objects between fields so that final report may appear as grid.

but my lines are crossing are each other. I am trying reduce the length of the lines by dragging the double arrow with the help of my mouse but somehow I am not able to get the precise length that I want.
it either gets short or exceeds the border and I want it finish just at the other line!

I am trying to view it in ASP.NET webpage via crystal report viewer

[image]

Comment: You may want to rethink posting email addresses, phone numbers, user IDs, etc. of anyone, let alone admins for what appears to be healthcare applications, on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Well it can be done !
Open your Report in VS2008. Select the line which u want to reduce the height.
Go to property window. There you can see the propreties "Top", "Bottom", "Left", "Right".
By adjusting the values in those properties, you can fit the line as your wish.
For your ref : [Possible Duplicate Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551371/issue-related-to-vertical-line-in-crystal-reports/9029471)

Hope this will fix your problem, if not pls comment.